# How to block a number in Twilio

Tags: c#, twilio

Problem statement:
A user comes to our web site and checks the check box to 'Un-Subscribe'.
Our system will remove corresponding cell phone number from our subscribers list.

But We want to make sure that twilio should also block that number. For this:

Q1: How can we ask twilio to block those number(s) using C# code; so that; if  by mistake we send SMS to this number; the SMS get blocked at twilio end at least.
Q2: In case we successfully blocked the number at twilio; How could we unblock those blocked number(s) at twilio, in future  using C#.

Thanks,
Saurabh

Comment: The title of your question should try to give a brief overview of your question. You shouldn't say something generic link "This is about SMS Messages".

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe that Twilio does support industry standards such as Stop, Block and Cancel.
You can read more about this here, http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-stop-block-and-cancel-aka-sms-filtering.

From that I take it that Twilio will respect a clients wish to prevent receiving further messages, should they choose to do so.